# Solving a recursive formula

Tags: recursion, quantum-mechanics

Can somebody please help me solve this?

$C_n$ = $2 D^{n-1}$ + $\hat{D}*C_{n-2} * \hat{D}$

where $C_1 = I_{2x2}$ and $C_2 = 2*D $ and D is a matrix operator**. I want to find $C_n$ in terms of D and n ONLY.

For those interested, this is actually a quantum mechanics harmonic oscillator problem. Define 
$C_n = [\hat{a}, \hat{a}_{+}^{n}], D = \hat{a}_{+}$.

where $a$ and $a_{+}$ are annihilation and creation operators.

Update: I found the answer using principles of physics = $C_n = n*D^{n-1} $.

**By Matrix operator, I mean an operator in matrix representation.

Comment: What's $C_2$ then? It's not defined yet.

Comment: Anything known about $D,M$, like are they invertible and/or do they commute?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: $C_2 = 2 D$. Does that help to solve it?

Comment: What is a matrix operator?

Comment: An operator in matrix representation. Why was this ambiguous?

Comment: @AdeelMahmood Because you didn't say "is a matrix."  Matrix operator sounds like some arbitrary function that operates on matrices.  There are large area of mathematics that study things like linear (non matrix) operators also.

Comment: I don't have time to write it up now, but I think you can solve this just by using the equation $C_{n+1} = 2~D\times D^{n-1} + \hat D \times C_{n-1} \times \hat D$ and eliminate the $D^{n-1}$ between the two equations to get a regular linear equation.